# Ruined command file location info

Tags: macos, gfortran, osx-yosemite

New to using gfortran with Yosemite Terminal, I  succeeded to run my program successfully until, after some accidental fiddling on Terminal window, I apparently ruined command file location info.

Supposing my Mac is Andys-iMAc and I am u1 (user) and my compile cmd were `gfortran -o txx text1709.f`, what should the right Terminal prompts and titles be and how do I get them back ?

Comment: Please select a title for your questions which says what is wrong or summarizes your question. I took something from your question, but find something better if possible. Please take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: I have no idea what happened form your description, please be more detailed.

Comment: I don't understand the question either. Did you delete a file by mistake? Or did you mess up the terminal settings and now can't see the prompt etc.?

Comment: Sorry about bad title.

Comment: Well, the title is not that important, but you have to explain what is going on, really.

Comment: Andys iMac: ~u1$ gfortran -o txx text1709.f

Comment: Here's Terminal dialogwith problems:

Comment: [edit] the question to show more info. Do not use comments.